# iOS Swift AVAudioPlayer playAtTime method doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

My code is very simple like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VC: UIViewController {
    var player:AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audioName", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do{
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            print("duration", player.duration)// duration 200
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.playAtTime(50.0)
        }catch{

        }

    }
}
```

when player.play() is called, the audio can play normally.
I don't know why the playAtTime function doesn't work.
Please help!

Comment: playAtTime may not play even with currentTime + someNumber, some number can play but some cannot. My answer is, set current time and call play() directly.

Answer (score 3):

playAtTime plays the sound at a time in the future, specified relative to the **device's current time**.  So the time parameter needs to be the current device time plus your required delay (in seconds):

```
player.playAtTime(player.currentDeviceTime + 50)
```

player.currentTime will be 0 when you initialise the player so this isn't the property to use.

Apple doc is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1389324-play)

Answer (score 2):

`func playAtTime(time: NSTimeInterval) -> Bool`
This function is meant to play the sound some time in the future, based on and greater than deviceCurrentTime, i would suggest to try:

`player.playAtTime(player.currentTime + 50.0)`